# Apache commons csv parsing trying reading next record behind size of collection

Tags: java, csv

I am using java library Apache commons-csv to parse csv.
The problem is I am getting IOException, I don't get it why
the Iterable CSVRecord is trying to compute next row
and end with exception. Its weird behaviour.

```java
 while (!parsedCorrectly && !failedOnException) {
            try (final Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file.getPath()), "UTF-8")){
                parser = new CSVParser(reader, format);
            } catch (IOException | IllegalArgumentException e) {
                LOG.debug("Headers contain duplicate name "+ e.getMessage());
                failedOnException = true;
                break;
            }

            if (parser != null) {
                try {
                    for (final CSVRecord record : parser) {
                        if (record.size() == 1 && !parsedCorrectly) {
                            format = setAlternativeParsingFormat(formatNumber);
                            formatNumber++;
                            break;
                        } else {
                            parsedCorrectly = true;
                        }
                        IssueInputParameters issueInputParameters = issueService.newIssueInputParameters();
                        try {
                            setOOTBFieldsToIssueInputParameters(issueInputParameters, record);
                        } catch (InvalidInputException e) {
                            addValidationErrorMessage(e.getMessage(), issueNumber);
                            valid = false;
                        }
                        Map<String, String> recordMap = record.toMap();
                        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : recordMap.entrySet()) {
                            CustomField customField = customFieldManager.getCustomFieldObjectsByName(
                                    entry.getKey()).stream().findFirst().orElse(null);
                            if (customField != null && entry.getValue() != null) {
                                addStringValueToIssueParameters(customField, issueInputParameters, entry.getValue(), issueNumber);

                                if (issueInputParameters.getCustomFieldValue(customField.getId()) == null) {
                                    issueInputParameters.addCustomFieldValue(customField.getId(), entry.getValue());
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        createIssue(issueInputParameters, issueNumber);
                        issueNumber++;
                        valid = true;
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    failedOnException = true;
                    LOG.debug("There was problem to import file");
                } finally {
                    if (parser != null) {
                        parser.close();
                    }
                }

            }

        }
```

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: IOException reading next record: java.io.IOException: Stream closed`

As you can see there is for loop in which I get exception trying to read next record which obviously doesn't exist.

Comment: could you please add the complete code snippet .

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to iterate over the initialized `CSVParser` when the underlying `Reader` has been already closed within the first `try-with-resources` block:

```java
try (final Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file.getPath()), "UTF-8")) { // the reader is closed when this code block exits
    parser = new CSVParser(reader, format);
}
//...
for (final CSVRecord record : parser) { // here you are accessing a closed resource
//...
```

You should keep the `Reader` open all along your parsing code process so that the input stream is kept open while you are reading items over the file.

Here down a slightly modified version of your code snippet:
*NB: Useless `if` check removed and both `Closeable` resources has been refactored to the same `try` block.*

```java
while (!parsedCorrectly && !failedOnException) {
    try (final Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file.getPath()), "UTF-8");
            CSVParser parser = new CSVParser(reader, format)) {
        for (final CSVRecord record : parser) {
            if (record.size() == 1 && !parsedCorrectly) {
                format = setAlternativeParsingFormat(formatNumber);
                formatNumber++;
                break;
            } else {
                parsedCorrectly = true;
            }
            IssueInputParameters issueInputParameters = issueService.newIssueInputParameters();
            try {
                setOOTBFieldsToIssueInputParameters(issueInputParameters, record);
            } catch (InvalidInputException e) {
                addValidationErrorMessage(e.getMessage(), issueNumber);
                valid = false;
            }
            Map<String, String> recordMap = record.toMap();
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : recordMap.entrySet()) {
                CustomField customField = customFieldManager.getCustomFieldObjectsByName(
                      entry.getKey()).stream().findFirst().orElse(null);
                if (customField != null && entry.getValue() != null) {
                    addStringValueToIssueParameters(customField, issueInputParameters, entry.getValue(), issueNumber);

                    if (issueInputParameters.getCustomFieldValue(customField.getId()) == null) {
                        issueInputParameters.addCustomFieldValue(customField.getId(), entry.getValue());
                    }
                }
            }
            createIssue(issueInputParameters, issueNumber);
            issueNumber++;
            valid = true;
        }
    } catch (IOException | IllegalArgumentException e) {
        LOG.debug("Headers contain duplicate name "+ e.getMessage());
        failedOnException = true;
        break;
    }
}
```